# Custom output form boilerpipe - Transform <p> into two newlines

Tags: java, boilerpipe

Im using boilerpipe to extract Text form Websites.

```
ArticleSentencesExtractor.getInstance().getText(inputHTMLStream)
```

I dont see any customization possibilities. I would like to separate `<p>sentence</p>` elements with two newlines. Is that possible - how?